# Unable to connect to smb share over USB

Tags: 16.04, usb, smb

I need little help here.
I have a Blackberry Z10, and I am not able to access its storage through smb via USB on Ubuntu 16. The feature works well on Ubuntu 14 though.

Here is what I have found out -

```
(On my Ubuntu 16 installation)
$ dpkg -l | egrep 'smb|samba'
ii libsmbclient:amd64
ii python-samba
ii samba-common
ii samba-common-bin
ii samba-libs:amd64
ii smbclient


$ diff lsmod_before_bb_connect.txt lsmod_after_bb_connect.txt
1a2,5
> cdc_mbim 16384 0
> cdc_wdm 20480 1 cdc_mbim
> cdc_ncm 32768 1 cdc_mbim
> usbnet 45056 2 cdc_mbim,cdc_ncm
99c103
< mii 16384 1 r8169
---
> mii 16384 2 r8169,usbnet

$ sudo nmap MY_USBNET_IP

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-12-02 19:15 IST
Nmap scan report for MY_USBNET_IP
Host is up (0.0020s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on MY_USBNET_IP are filtered

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 21.68 seconds

(On Ubuntu 14 live session)
$ sudo nmap MY_USBNET_IP

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-12-02 14:40 UTC
Nmap scan report for MY_USBNET_IP
Host is up (0.0021s latency).
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open http
139/tcp open netbios-ssn
443/tcp open https
445/tcp open microsoft-ds
1111/tcp open lmsocialserver
8443/tcp open https-alt

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 76.95 seconds
```

Firewall status says it's inactive on my computer.

I have no clue how to fix this, can anyone here help me?

Thanks.

I have already enabled 'Access via Wifi' in my phone settings.

Comment: Are you trying to access the usb over the network, or attached to your localhost? nmap is for seeing open ports on networked devices, not usb ports. English overloading the word 'port'... However, I do see a tutorial online saying that blackberry provides ip network access over usb though that can be used by ubuntu to connect to it's internal smb storage. Do you have samba installed and the ntfs-3g package for ntfs support (this may not be needed) installed?

Comment: My device emulates itself as a usb ethernet interface (actually 2 interfaces, one for debugging), or at least that's how it appears to me. It then connects using that interface, and assigns an IP address to the pc. I passed the phone's IP address to  nmap in the test above.
I have Samba installed, and I can access the smb share on my phone through WLAN, but not through USB.

Would you please share the link of the tutorial you referred to?

Comment: I believe this is the one I found yesterday. http://atodorov.org/blog/2013/07/17/tip-how-to-enable-usb-networking-between-blackberry-z10-and-red-hat-enterprise-linux-6/

Comment: Yes that's the procedure I follow. What's different though is that with the new update we don't need to manually select 'Windows' or 'Mac' on phone, infact no such option exists now.
The problem I could make out is that ports 445 and 139 appear to be filtered to Ubuntu. Might be a problem with the driver. In desperation I even replaced the usbnet kernel module binary with the one installed with Ubuntu14(4.4.0.39) but that won't load. Could you suggest me something that might work?

Comment: If those are filtered ports, and they were open before the update, it is possible that you just need to open up those ports using ufw, the ubuntu firewall program. Try turning off the ufw service when accessing the device, that will tell if it is the firewall.
Does it present you any options at all when connecting with it like 'Windows' or 'Mac'?

Comment: I actually was referring to the phone OS update, BB10.2.1 did not have this Win/Mac option ever since its arrival AFAIR. Regarding ufw, I already had checked it and ufw reported that it's disabled(as I had stated in original post). Moreover I can access smb shares using WLAN, so my understanding removes firewall from the list of potent causes of the issue. BTW I have zero experience with ufw. . . . The USB host OS detection is now automated in BB10. With mass storage turned off, when I connect my Z10 to linux, 2 new network interfaces show up. Windows -> few options apear 'Install driver' etc

Comment: I wonder if there is a kernel module you need to install in linux to support this new network since windows prompts about it on connect? Maybe check the bb website for drivers for linux? You could try the live distro of arch or openSuse that have the most up to date drivers since they are rolling releases. Both worth a check. Does audacity or ragnarok recognize this device? If you run 'udevadm monitor' while plugging in the device, does udev recognize it and do any automated actions?

Comment: I just found a workaround brother! :) Ubuntu 16 was adding 3 new entries in the routing table against 1 entry in 14, when the phone was connected. Of these 3, I deleted the entry named <Z10_hostname>.local which had flags UGH set and genmask all ones. The other extra entry did not appear to cause any trouble. Nautilus can happily connect to my device now :). Thanks for bearing with me, I appreciate it.

Comment: great to hear! I was hoping you would find a way to get this working, was an interesting problem to troubleshoot. I am always happy to help, feel free to post again. Have a great day!